# Ошибка HRESULT 0х80010105 при работе с Access

Tags: .net, access, com, office

Есть приложение, которое работает с Access, где вылетает HRESULT 0х80010105.

Как поправить ошибку я разобрался: Установить Access DataBase Engine

Программа работает, но после того, как я открываю любую БД руками в Access, то мой Office 2013 начинается выполнять конфигурирование и после чего, приложение, опять перестает работать и выкидывает ошибку выше.

Подскажите, что мне делать и как избежать слета ?

Система х64, офис х32, Access DataBase Engine x32.

Фрагмент кода:

```
 app = new Application();
        app.Visible = false;
        app.Screen.Application.Visible = false;
        app.Application.UserControl = false;
        app.UserControl = false;
        app.OpenCurrentDatabase(pathToDatabase);//<--Ошибка вот тут.
```

Кстати, эта ошибка распространяется не только на interop, но и на OleDb. В момент открытия соединения. Если переустановить Access DataBase Engine, то все работает, до того момента, как я запущу приложение Access, которое выполнит переконфигурацию и OleDb снова перестает работать.

Comment: К сожалению, была та же ошибка и тоже с офисом 2013. После установки 2010-го ошибка исчезла. Только нужно внимательно почистить реестр.

Comment: На каком этапе происходит ошибка? Какая функция возвращает её? Приведите минимальный самодостаточный фрагмент кода.

Comment: @Arhad добавил.

Comment: сервис запущен? сервер работает?

Comment: версия базы совпадает с версией сервера?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, что вы имеете ввиду по Сервером? Я открываю базу формата 2003, а этот формат поддерживается во всех современных Access.